# Need help setting up google calendar API

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am using a CAR Wash booking system a codecanyon plugin, i want to make make my plugin work two way google calendar sync. I want to trigger a function in this file so when i make changes in google calendar they should update in WP plugin. This is a Car Was booking system.

Main code are in plugin as follow:

```
<?php


class CBSGoogleCalendar
{

/**************************************************************************/

function __construct()
{
    $this->token=get_option(PLUGIN_CBS_CONTEXT.'_google_calendar_token','');
    $this->expiration=get_option(PLUGIN_CBS_CONTEXT.'_google_calendar_expiration','');
    $this->settings=json_decode(get_option(PLUGIN_CBS_CONTEXT.'_google_calendar_settings',''));
}

/**************************************************************************/

function insertBooking($bookingId)
{
    $token=$this->getToken();
    if(!$token)return(false);

    if(!($bookingId>0))return(false);

    $Booking=new CBSBooking();
    $Location=new CBSLocation();

    $booking=$Booking->getBooking($bookingId);
    if(!count($booking))return(false);

    $location_id=$booking['meta']['location_id'];       
    $location=$Location->getDictionary(array
    (
        'location_id'                                                       => $location_id,
    ));

    if(!count($booking))return(false);

    $Timezone=new DateTimeZone($this->getTimezoneString());

    $start=$booking['meta']['date'].' '.$booking['meta']['time'];
    $startDate=new DateTime($start,$Timezone);

    $endDate=clone $startDate;
    $endDate->modify('+'.$booking['meta']['duration'].' minutes');

    $bookingDescription=sprintf(__('<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a><br>Client: %s %s',PLUGIN_CBS_DOMAIN),admin_url('post.php').'?post='.$bookingId.'&action=edit',$booking['post']->post_title,$booking['meta']['client_first_name'],$booking['meta']['client_second_name']);

    $bookingDetails=array
    (
        'summary'                                                           =>  $booking['post']->post_title,
        'description'                                                       =>  $bookingDescription,
        'location'                                                          =>  $booking['meta']['location_name'],
        'start'                                                             =>  array
        (
            'dateTime'                                                      =>  $startDate->format(DateTime::RFC3339),
        ),
        'end'                                                               =>  array
        (
            'dateTime'                                                      =>  $endDate->format(DateTime::RFC3339),
        ),
    );

    $ch=curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'.$location[$location_id]['meta']['google_calendar_id'].'/events?access_token='.$token);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($bookingDetails));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    $response=curl_exec($ch);
    $responseDecoded=json_decode($response);
    curl_close($ch);

    if((is_object($responseDecoded)) && (property_exists($responseDecoded,'kind')) && ($responseDecoded->kind=='calendar#event')) return(true);

    return(false);
}

/**************************************************************************/

function getCalendarList()
{
    $token=$this->getToken();
    if(!$token)return(false);

    $ch=curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?access_token='.$token);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    $response=curl_exec($ch);
    $responseDecoded=json_decode($response);

    curl_close($ch);

    if(is_object($responseDecoded) && property_exists($responseDecoded,'kind') && $responseDecoded->kind=='calendar#calendarList') return($responseDecoded);
    return(false);
}

/**************************************************************************/

function getToken()
{
    if(is_null($this->settings))
        return(false);

    if($this->token && $this->expiration && $this->expiration>time())
        return($this->token);

    $header='{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}';
    $headerEncoded=$this->base64urlEncode($header);

    $assertionTime=time();
    $expirationTime=$assertionTime+3600;
    $claimSet='{
      "iss":"'.$this->settings->client_email.'",
      "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
      "aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
      "exp":'.$expirationTime.',
      "iat":'.$assertionTime.'
    }';
    $claimSetEncoded=$this->base64urlEncode($claimSet);

    $signature='';
    openssl_sign($headerEncoded.'.'.$claimSetEncoded,$signature,$this->settings->private_key,'SHA256');
    $signatureEncoded=$this->base64urlEncode($signature);
    $assertion=$headerEncoded.'.'.$claimSetEncoded.'.'.$signatureEncoded;

    $ch=curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion='.$assertion);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    $response=curl_exec($ch);
    $responseDecoded=json_decode($response);

    curl_close($ch);

    if(is_object($responseDecoded) && property_exists($responseDecoded,'access_token'))
    {
        $this->token=$responseDecoded->access_token;
        $this->expiration=$expirationTime;
        update_option(PLUGIN_CBS_CONTEXT.'_google_calendar_token',$responseDecoded->access_token);
        update_option(PLUGIN_CBS_CONTEXT.'_google_calendar_expiration',$expirationTime);
        return($responseDecoded->access_token);
    }

    return(false);
}

/**************************************************************************/

function base64urlEncode($data)
{
    return(rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data),'+/','-_'),'='));
}

/**************************************************************************/

function getTimezoneString()
{
    $timezoneString=get_option('timezone_string');
    if(!$timezoneString)
    {
        $gmtOffset=get_option('gmt_offset');
        $timezoneString=timezone_name_from_abbr('',$gmtOffset*3600,false);
        if($timezoneString===false)
            $timezoneString=timezone_name_from_abbr('',0,false);
    }
    return($timezoneString);        
}

/**************************************************************************/

}
```

Comment: Please clarify what happens and what you would expect to happen instead.

Comment: This plugin sync only one way, Like when a booking add into plugin so google calendar syncs customer name, appointment, time date, months and year. But i want differently Once there is a booking plugin so i want to able to modify booking through google calendar and changes should affect in plugin's booking